# Concat number to string, number always returns zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my db called `storageFolder`. All rows in said column contain the value 8 and is set INT (4).

In my SELECT query, I'm trying to return this column with a prefix of 'group', to make the record read 'group8'.

I am trying to use CONCAT to do this, like this:

```
SELECT photoID, CONCAT('group',storageFolder) AS storageFolder FROM photos
```

But this always gets returned, with a zero:

```
storageFolder
----------------
group0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is really its giving the values `group0` and `storageFolder` having 8 ? I think you should to check once again. I was tried with this and its concating the integer value as well. May be the mysql version's problem.

Comment: @Bajrang: I think I do have a problem elsewhere. That column used to be VARCHAR with 'group8' as value. I recently modified it to be INT(4) and the value of '8'. Maybe something went wrong there. My value still reads '8' in phpMyAdmin. There is no obvious reason.

Comment: Which column you have modified it to be INT(4), Is this `storageFolder` ?

Comment: I have fixed this now. Yes, this was `storageFolder` column. I removed it completely and re-created it again. Seems to work now. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem. My column used to be a VARCHAR with the value of 'group8', I recently modified it to be an INT(4) with a value of '8'. Not sure what would have caused this error doing that. Anyway, I deleted the column and re-created it and works as intended. Strange!

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT photoID, CONCAT('group', CAST(storageFolder AS CHAR)) AS storageFolder FROM   photos
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I've managed to fix it. My column used to be a VARCHAR with the value of 'group8', I recently modified it to be an INT(4) with a value of '8'. Not sure what would have caused this error doing that. Anyway, I deleted the column and re-created it and works as intended. Strange!

Answer (score 3):

Try CASTING the `storageFolder` to a string before you concatenate it:

```
SELECT photoID, 
       CONCAT('group', CAST(storageFolder AS CHAR(10))) AS storageFolder
FROM   photos
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I've managed to fix it. My column used to be a VARCHAR with the value of 'group8', I recently modified it to be an INT(4) with a value of '8'. Not sure what would have caused this error doing that. Anyway, I deleted the column and re-created it and works as intended. Strange!